# Assign permissions to a custom Property set in active directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to setup a custom property set in Active Directory (2008R2) and I can't seem to figure out how to apply permissions based on the set.    More specifically,   we need to add a number of new attributes (25+) and several processes/depts need to read/write to specific attributes.   Also,  some of the attributes will contain confidential information.

To simplify permissions {read keep dacls list shorter},   I wanted to create several custom property sets and apply permissions to these  {similar to General-Information}    If the attributes help confidential information I was going to set the attributes searchflag to 128 {[conf bit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922836)}    Then read permissions could be added via a group with read access {via ldp}

I have the custom [property sets](http://blog.ilmbestpractices.com/2011/12/property-sets-for-permissions-in-ad-and.html) configured and they look ok.    The thing is,  when I open ldp.exe to set an ace,   I do not see them listed under propset or control access right.     We have used this method for attributes in the past and it works well,   only down side is the dacls list will get a bit unwieldy with this many attributes.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Property sets are availalbe in AD Users & Computers.  I think you have to have **Advanced Features** turned on from the **View** menu.  Open the properties for the container, select **Security** and click the **Advanced** button.  When you Add or Edit the ACE click the **Properties** tab.  That will list all of the property sets first followed by the individual properties.

In LDP right-click the container and select **Advanced > Security Descriptor**.  Click OK to accept the DN of the object you just selected.  What's flakey about LDP is that the **Add ACE** and **Edit ACE** buttons aren't available until you select one of the existng ACEs.  But from that dialog the property sets are listed in the **Object type** drop down.

One other thing to remember if you are creating new attributes and new property sets is that the property set is linked to the attribute through the Schema.  So this won't be available to existing objects until they get synchronized with the schema updates using something like **ldapmodify**.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, property sets are defined in the Schema. When you define them, you should make sure that you have correctly and completely defined them, meaning that you should also ensure that the UI related attributes that are used by GUI clients when enumerating the list of property sets from the Schema are correctly specified.

I would suggest taking a look a second look at your property set descriptions to ensure that the UI related attributes are also defined correctly. Once defined correctly, any AD aware client that is developed correctly should have the means to show you these property sets.